# Grid view not showing the first row ASP.NET , C# Sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to show data from my SQL table on grid view, however, it is not showing the first row of data but the following rows of data a showing: Here is my code

```
public partial class DisplayGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostbankConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //query 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataReader reader;
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (reader.Read())
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            //Bind the data
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, probably this is caused because of your if(reader.Read()) that reads the first row. However you should not bind the reader to the grid. rather a list or a datatable.

Comment: I should use a Listview instead?

Comment: Instead of  `if (reader.Read())` replace it with `if (reader.HasRows())`. I think that's what you need

Comment: it says non- invocable member 'system.data.common.dbDataReader.HasRows cannot be used like a method

Comment: `if (reader.HasRows)` is the correct one. Afterwards you can call `while(reader.Read())` to iterate the reader.

Comment: Sorry its an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_HasRows) not a method hence it should be `if (reader.HasRows)`

Comment: Thank you if (reader.HasRows) worked :)

Comment: @Makaziwe sorry for the late reply. To bind a Grid View i would use a List<T>. In you Exmaple a List<User>. Then dealing with DataAccess in a UI Page is also bad design. I would put that code outside in a service layer.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `DataTable` and load contents of `SqlDataReader` with `DataTable.Load()` instead of assigning the reader contents directly to `GridView` instance:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows) // check if the reader contains rows
        {
            dt.Load(reader); // load to Datatable

            GridView1.DataSource = dt; // assign data source from DataTable
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `SqlDataReader` is [forward-only stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders), you need to use `DataTable` or other collections which able to perform both backward and forward lookups.

Answer (score 1):

remove the line-  `if (reader.Read())`
because DataReader.Read method advances the SqlDataReader to the next record.

Here is the code-

```
public partial class DisplayGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostbankConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //query 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataReader reader;
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           GridView1.DataSource = reader;
           //Bind the data
            GridView1.DataBind();
            reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you found this helpful,kindly mark the solution as answer so that it can help others in future reference. Thank you!